# Authentication flow with jwt and socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, jwt

My Socket.IO application requires that a user be authenticated before he/she can send a message and be connected for reading messages without authentication.

Below is a code sample based on the assumption that the client would login via a REST API, obtain a JWT and reconnect with the socket server using the received token:

```
var socket = io.connect('', {
  query: 'token=' + token
});
```

How do I construct the authentication flow for the application?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your Problem? Do you would like to know how you handle the jwt? Or when to make which call for login and obtaining a token? In my application the user logins via rest api getting a token and the you can use it like for example with these module https://github.com/auth0/socketio-jwt

Comment: when to make which call for login and obtaining a token!
because user from beginning should be connected to socket to get messages real time but for sending messages being authenticated is required.


Consider i retrieve jwt token from api, how can I append to socket requsts that token .

Comment: Ah ok in this case you open the socket first for reading the new messages. Then if user would like to send a message you make the login call with the user credentials and getting back a valid jwt in the response. This jwt you use to make the socket events to write a message. You can als save the jwt in your app so you can use it as long it is not expired. And if it expires you have to do the login again.

Comment: Yes. I wonder to knew if flow is right, and is there any way to append token in every socket.io request without reconnecting?